# How to prevent Elasticsearch from flattening 2D arrays in "fields"-containing query

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

Nested arrays get flattened when represented in "fields". I expect that values from the same path to be merged, but that the internal data structure will not be modified.

Could someone explain whether I am doing something incorrectly, or whether this belongs as an Elasticsearch issue?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create the 2D data

   ```
   curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/5 -d '{ "data": [ [100],[2,3],[6,7] ] }'
   ```
2. Query the data, specifying fields

   ```
   curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/5/_search -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"*"} }, "fields":["data"] } }'
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   {"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"test","_type":"5","_id":"AVdsHJrepOClGTFyoGqo","_score":1.0,"fields":{"data":[100,2,3,6,7]}}]}}
   ```
3. Repeat without the use of "fields":

   ```
   curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/5/_search -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"*"} } } }'
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   {"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"test","_type":"5","_id":"AVdsHJrepOClGTFyoGqo","_score":1.0,"_source":{ "data": [ [100],[2,3],[6,7] ] }}]}}
   ```

Notice that _source and fields differ, in that "fields" decomposes the 2D array into a 1D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of specifying "fields" I usually do [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html)

Your query would change to something like:

```
curl -XGET <IPADDRESS>:9200/test/5/_search -d '{"_source":{"include": ["data"]}, "query":{"query_string":{"query":"*"} }}'
```

Comment: Andrey, please fix this answer: '{"_source":{"include": "data"}, "query":{"query_string":{"query":"*"} }}' (missing bracket. Also, while this provide a useful demonstration of how to avoid requesting unnecessary fields, could you provide an explanation for why fields flatten's 2D arrays? This was part of the question.

Comment: @AlexeiKotlar - I wasn't sure why it flattens the arrays but Uli's post makes sense - lucene indexes arrays of arrays as flat arrays so it can only retrieve flat version when you specify `field` request property. 
We both have pieces of the full answer, please mark the one you feel is more useful :)

Answer (score 3):

When you specify nothing else in your request, what you get back foreach hit is the "_source" object, that is, *exactly* the Json you sent to ES during indexing (even including whitespace!).

When you use source filtering, as Andrey suggests, it's the same except you can include or exclude certain fields.

When you use the "fields" directive in your query, the return values are not taken from the _source, but read directly from the Lucene Index. (see [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html)) Now the key in your search response will switch from "_source" to "fields" to reflect this change.

As alkis said:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html
These docs say up front that, yes, Elasticsearch does flatten arrays.

Comment: I was silly in my 2nd example, I could have just stated that the fields and _source fields differed, in that 2D arrays are flattened. I think your answer is almost there. Does lucene respect 2D arrays?

Comment: This is a great answer regarding the internals of ES!

Answer (score 2):

From here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html
it seems that elasticsearch considers them the same.

```
In Elasticsearch, there is no dedicated array type. Any field can contain zero or more values by default, however, all values in the array must be of the same datatype. For instance:

an array of strings: [ "one", "two" ]
an array of integers: [ 1, 2 ]
an array of arrays: [ 1, [ 2, 3 ]] which is the equivalent of [ 1, 2, 3 ]
an array of objects: [ { "name": "Mary", "age": 12 }, { "name": "John", "age": 10 }]
```

You could use an array of json objects and use nested data type with nested query.

Maybe nested data type could be helpful

```
PUT /my_index

PUT /my_index/_mapping/my_type
{
    "properties" : {
      "data" : {
        "type" : "nested",
          "properties": {
          "value" : {"type": "long" }
        }
      }
    }
}

POST /my_index/my_type
{
  "data": [
    { "value": [1, 2] },
    { "value": [3, 4] }
  ]
}

POST /my_index/my_type
{
  "data": [
    { "value": [1, 5] }
  ]
}

GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "data.value": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "data.value": 2
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers the "why" of the question. However, it does not provide as good a solutions as Andrey's, because nested queries force me to significantly change the way data is mapped. They seem to be intended for relating sets (whether something co-exists with something else). In my use case arrays have a different meaning: across fields values are stored in arrays to represent the same relationships; to replicate this using nested map, I'd need to roughly double the size of my indices, which is ridiculous. I will accept this answer if we can credit @Andrey for the practical solution.

Comment: No reason to not choose the answer that provided you a solution (Andrey's in this occasion). I agree that nested is not for your use case. The upvote and more importantly the interesting use case of yours and the solution provided are more than enough for me. Have fun

Comment: great. I appreciate your answer, it was valuable to my understanding of the subject. Thanks!